# DOTNET_ROOT Not Recognised After Raspbian Reboot

Tags: .net-core, raspbian

I have been following some basic tutorials for `dotnet` with `Raspbian`

They state:

```
export DOTNET_ROOT=$HOME/dotnet-arm32 
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/dotnet-arm32
```

However, when I reboot these are lost.  After some reading I found that adding `PATH=$PATH:$HOME/dotnet-arm32` to my `~/.profile` solved the `dotnet` command issue, but the `DOTNET_ROOT` does not work.  I have to run `export DOTNET_ROOT=$HOME/dotnet-arm32` once I've rebooted to get a project to run.

This is what my `~/.profile` looks like at the bottom of the file.

```
# set PATH to dotnet
PATH="$PATH:$HOME/dotnet-arm32"

# set ENV for runtime
DOTNET_ROOT="$HOME/dotnet-arm32"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to export the variables:

```sh
# set PATH to dotnet
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/dotnet-arm32"

# set ENV for runtime
export DOTNET_ROOT="$HOME/dotnet-arm32"
```

`PATH` was already an exported variable, so not exporting it doesn't make a difference. But `DOTNET_ROOT` is treated as a local variable in .profile unless it's exported explicitly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer - you mean just have `export` before `DOTNET_ROOT` and leave `PATH` as it is, or add `export` to `PATH` too?

Comment: Doesn't hurt to add export in PATH. I would add it to both.

Comment: I wrote a blog post to try and explain the relevance of `export`: https://omajid.github.io/posts/2020-06-25-variables-and-environment-variables/